# error building ruby 1.9.2 on arm machine

Tags: ruby, configure, arm

I am trying to build ruby 1.9.2 from source on a synology diskstation running an arm-linux. the dev-tools are installed, so are headers and libs. when I run ./configure pthread is not found

```
checking for pthread_kill in -lthr... no
checking for pthread_kill in -lpthread... no
checking for pthread_kill in -lpthreads... no
checking for pthread_kill in -lc... no
checking for pthread_kill in -lc_r... no
checking for pthread_kill in -lroot... no
configure: WARNING: "Don't know how to find pthread library on your system -- thread support disabled"
...
configure: error: thread model is missing
```

and no make file is created. As far as I can tell the pthread libs are present

```
> locate pthread
/lib/libpthread.so.0
/volume1/@optware/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/libpthread-2.5.so
/volume1/@optware/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/libpthread.so
/volume1/@optware/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/libpthread.so.0
/volume1/@optware/include/pthread.h
/volume1/@optware/include/bits/pthreadtypes.h
/volume1/@optware/lib/libpthread_nonshared.a
/volume1/homes/Jan/ruby-1.9.2-p290/thread_pthread.c
/volume1/homes/Jan/ruby-1.9.2-p290/thread_pthread.h
```

I tried telling configure where to find libs with --prefix --exec-prefix and $LIBS but to no avail. I would like to get around a cross compile and build it on the machine...
thanks

Comment: Does that version of pthreads implement that method? Not sure if --disable-pthreads will work. A cross-compile won't help if the arch thread lib doesn't have the function.

Answer (score 2):

The way to solve this issue is by using another set of libpthread libraries. See http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=30132 (although this is an answer to another issue, it does solve the configure issue).